# PYTHON: Extracting data from .xlsx using pandas ExcelWriter and outputting as text on image using PIL

Tags: python, pandas, python-imaging-library

1 /
**Data:**

```
Column A     Column B     Column C
AAA          1230         CCC    
ABA          4560         CDC
AAb          7890         CCD
...
```

2 /
**Set-up (*pandas*):**

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")...
```

3 /
**Formatting (e.g. for first row):**

```
# no formatting for Column A > AAA

# for Column B > 1,230
print(f"{1230:,d}")

# for Column C > ccc
print("CCC".lower())
```

4 /
Once accomplished, the data needs to be printed on an image.
**Set-up (*PIL*):**

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw
img = Image.open("input.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 10)
draw.text((10, 10), Column A data, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
draw.text((10, 20), Column B data, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
draw.text((20, 20), Column C data, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
img.save("output.jpg")
```

5 /
**Finished product:**

[image: "AAA", "1,230", "ccc"]

^ This is an example of the output of row #1 (if successful), what am I missing here? How can I *loop* it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `variable = f"{1230:,d}"` instead of `print(f"{1230:,d}")` and now you can use `variable` with `draw.text()`

Comment: `for row in df.iterrow(): ... draw.text()`

Comment: I don't know if `PIL` can draw multiline text so you will have to calculate position for every row.

Comment: Great thanks @furas ! Will try out a tuple and variable solution and see if it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw

df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")
tuples = [tuple(r) for r in df.to_numpy().tolist()]

maxtpp = len(tuples)
count = 0

while count <= maxtpp:
    (Column A, Column B, Column C) = tuples[count]

    Column B = f"{Column B:,d}"
    Column C = Column C.lower()

    img = Image.open("input.jpg")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 10)
    draw.text((10, 10), Column A, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
    draw.text((10, 20), Column B, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
    draw.text((20, 20), Column C, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
    count = count + 1
    img.save("output.jpg")
    if count > maxtpp:
        break
```

**Illustration of output:**

[image: Refer to question above]